# What is the best way of converting this error message into an SQL statement using vim?

Tags: vim

When working on a developer database, I frequently get an error message which implies that I need to run a simple SQL statement to clean up the database, based on the contents of the error message. However it is a pain to cut and paste from the error message to create the appropriate SQL statement, so what I would like to do is run a few commands from Vim to construct the SQL statement, and I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to do it. The format of the error message is:

```
com/changelogs/1-changelog1.xml::changelog1name::dev1 is now: 30e70b7
com/changelogs/2-changelog2.xml::changelog2name::dev5 is now: 4jkerui
com/changelogs/7-changelog1.xml::changelog7name::dev4 is now: 43jer7r
```

I need to null out the md5sum column for each of the offending changelogs, so I need to convert the above error message to an SQL statement in the format:

```
update databasechangelog set md5sum=null where id in
('changelog1name','changelog2name','changelog3name')
```

So, for example, in Vim, I could do something like:

Extract the changelog names:

```
:%s/^.*::\(.*\)::.*$/\1/g
```

Add a single quote to the start of each line:

```
:%s/^/'/g
```

Add a closing quote and comma to the end of each line:

```
:%s/$/',/g
```

After this I can type in the leading part of the SQL statement and the conversion is complete. However, typing in these commands is a pain, and what I would like to do is have the sequence of commands aliased to a keypress or user defined command in Vim. I've tried the following in my .vimrc but it only runs the first command:

```
noremap <F2> :%s/^.*::\(.*\)::.*$/\1/g | :%s/^/'/g
```

Hence my questions are:

1. What is the best way to achieve the conversion? Are the above commands sensible, or is there a more efficient way? e.g. a command that will extract all of the names and construct the correctly formatted list in a single command, rather than three commands
2. What is the best way to configure Vim to run all of the commands in a sequence, based on a keypress or user-defined command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your individual commands do what you want, you run all of them with a single mapping:

```
nnoremap <F2> :%s/^.*::\(.*\)::.*$/\1/g <bar> %s/^/'/g <bar> %s/$/',/g<CR>
```

See `:help map_bar`.